# Credit card for low CIBIL Score?

Tags: credit-card, india, credit-score, credit

I have CIBIL score of 628.
I want to improve it using credit card. I applied in one bank but they declined it.  Is any bank provide credit card for this score in India?

Comment: can get Captial One credit card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be difficult to get a credit card with low score. Best is talk to you Bank where you have savings account / FD. Ask them if they can issue a credit card with lower limit against the FD balance.

Do not apply randomly to all Banks, ever time there is an enquiry, your score would further decrease.

Comment: ok. but  i need credit card. Is any bank provide credit card for this score?

Comment: @Karthikeyan For this score it is unlikely you will get a credit card. But if you work with your bank, say keep an FD of Rs 50,000 as lien with them; they may give you a card with limit of Rs 30,000 say. You can then use it and improve your score. There may also be some co-operative bank that may sanction a credit card. You have to look around and explain the situation. By default your card application would more likely get rejected.

Comment: can u give ur email address to contact?

Comment: @Dheer  Ohhhhh.... very bad move mentioning cooperative banks. Now the OP is posting [questions](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/56760/5760) every [fifteen minutes](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/56759/5760) demanding lists of cooperative banks.

Comment: @DilipSarwate guilty as charged :). I was in 2 minds added the co-operative line as edit. Good learning.